# Brace expansion on multiword command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expansion

How do I perform brace expansion on a multi-word command?

If I try:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey{1..3}/
```

This produces:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey1/ s3://mybucket/mykey2/     s3://mybucket/mykey3/
```

But what I'm looking for is:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey1/
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey2/
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey3/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to wrap that in a loop:

```
for i in {1..3}; do aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey$i/; done
```